# Python: How do I scale the points in this plot properly on the x-axis?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

This is my dataset:

```
Date           Price    Peak     Trough
01-Jan-2002    33.78    False    False
02-Jan-2002    34.19    False    False
03-Jan-2002    35.44    False    False
04-Jan-2002    36.75    True     False
05-Jan-2002    32.28    False    True
```

I want to plot the **Price** as a line graph with the Date as X-axis. Whenever Peak is **True** there should be a green point on the line and whenever Trough is **True** there should be a  red point on the line.

Should look like this:

[image: Example]

The best solution would be if I could just code it so it makes the point whenever the condition is True. But I don't know how so what I tried is to make two new dataframes. In df1 are all data points where Peak is True, in df2 are all points where Trough is True. I then tried to plot 3 dataframes in one plot like this:

```
df.plot(x = 'Date', y = 'Price', figsize=(16,10))
plt.scatter(x = dfP['Date'], y = dfP['Price'], c = 'green')
plt.scatter(x = dfT['Date'], y = dfT['Price'], c = 'red')
plt.yscale('log')
```

However, it doesn't scale the points properly:

[image: Plot]

How can I scale the dates properly for the points? Or is there an easier way alltogether where I can just set the point whenever the condition is true? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Solution was to not mix pandas with matplotlib. Code now looks like this:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,10))
plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Dow Chemical Company (The)'])
plt.scatter(x = dfP['Date'], y = dfP['Dow Chemical Company (The)'], c = 'green')
plt.scatter(x = dfT['Date'], y = dfT['Dow Chemical Company (The)'], c = 'red')
plt.yscale('log')
```

All the points are now displayed properly on the line, but it shows every single date on the x-axis which I need to fix.

Comment: Don't mix pandas and matplotlib when plotting datetime. Either use `df.plot` throughout, or `plt.plot/scatter`, but not both, because they have different unit conversions for datetime.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed it to matplotlib and now the points are properly displayed on the line. The only problem as of know is that it shows every single date on the x-axis: https://i.imgur.com/xgVe3Ce.png Do you happen to know how to fix this issue?

Comment: This would happen if you use strings instead of datetime objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I realize these may be simple questions but as a beginner I appreaciate it greatly.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was to use matplotlib's [`markevery`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/markevery_demo.html), which adds circles on a line, but they have to be the same colour as the line. I think your apporach with separate `scatter` plots is correct. I just replaced True with `Price` and `False` with `NaN`. (Make a copy if necessary!) Got close enough to your desired output:

```
df.loc[df.Peak, 'Peak'] = df.loc[df.Peak, 'Price']
df.loc[df.Trough, 'Trough'] = df.loc[df.Trough, 'Price']
df = df.replace(False, np.NaN)

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.grid()
plt.plot(df.set_index('Date')['Price'], color='b', label='sunspot_SWO')
plt.scatter(df.Date, troughs, label='min', color='r')
plt.scatter(df.Date, peaks, label='max', color='g')
plt.legend(loc='lower right');
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. I got it to work by using matplotlib instead of pandas. I tried your version too but got an error message in the first line: "None of [Index(['False', 'False', 'False', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False',\n       'False', 'False',\n       ...\n       'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False',\n       'False', 'False'],\n      dtype='object', length=2609)] are in the [index]". If I comment the first two rows out I get an error because 'troughs' and 'peaks' are not defined.